# JBoss fails to deploy an application due to "Failed to create a new SAX parser" error

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I have to confess that I am not familiar with jboss, but I have a task to launch application that works on top of it. The application was running before restart but is not able to get launched after. The following exception is raised on attempt to run it:

```
12:40:08,680 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
12:40:08,777 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/geoserver
12:40:08,971 ERROR [JBossContextConfig] XML error parsing: context.xml
org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX    parser
at    org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:100)
at  org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.processContextConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:557)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.init(JBossContextConfig.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4148)
```

Are there any typical causes for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown when you package XML parser jars (eg. xerces or SAXParser) in your deployment artifact (ie. WAR, EAR) files. JBoss provides its own XML parsing libraries which is available to your application as part of the parent class loader. You may also need to re-compile your application against the JBoss run time libraries. A good rule of thumb is to not duplicate jars that are already provided by the JEE container. You can work around it by implementing classloading isolation, however, I think it's best to start by removing the JEE container provided jars first.